# If $f'(a)=f''(a)=0$ but $a$ is not an inflection point, then must $a$ be a maximum or minimum?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be twice-differentiable and $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $f'(a)=f''(a)=0$ but $a$ is not an inflection point, then must $a$ be a maximum point or a minimum point?

Comment: What you know is that: if $f''(a) > 0$,  then f has a minimum in $a$ and if $f''(a) < 0$, then f has a maximum in $a$.

Comment: @LuísaBorsato That doesn't seem to help here, as OP specified that $f''(a) = 0$.

Comment: No, consider the function $f:x\mapsto x^6sin(1/x)$. This is twice defferentiable even at 0. We also have $f'(0)=f''(0)=0$. But this is neither a maximum, a minimum nor an inflexion point.

Comment: FYI, when the first two (or more) derivatives at a point are zero, there is still the possibility of applying the [Higher-order derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f(x) := \cases{x^5 \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right) &for $x \neq 0$ \\ 0 &for $x = 0$ }$$
Invoking the difference quotient definition of derivative shows that $f$ is $C^2$ at $0$ and that $f'(0) = f''(0) = 0$, but $f$ takes on both positive and negative values on any (arbitrarily small) interval containing $0$, so $f$ has neither a minimum nor a maximum at $x = 0$.

If one has defined an inflection point of a $C^2$ function $g$ to be a value $a$ so that there is some interval $I \ni a$ such that $g''$ is negative (positive) on $I \cap \{x < a\}$ and positive (negative) on $I \cap \{x > a\}$, then we can see that $0$ is not an inflection point of $f$, as $f''$ also takes on both positive and negative values on any (arbitrarily small) interval containing $0$.

Comment: +1: I love weird/pathological functions...great reminder how intuition can fail.

Comment: Thanks, @Bey. You might be interested in this classic reference: https://books.google.at/books?id=D_XBAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=counterexamples+in+analysis&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=counterexamples%20in%20analysis&f=false

Comment: I have a doubt --- is the second derivative continuous at 0? Because $f''(x)=12x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x} - 6x \cos \frac{1}{x}  - \sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ would seem to fluctuate between -1 and 1 as $x \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @KennyLJ Oops, you're right! Thanks for pointing this out. It's $4$ that's the critical value, in that $|x|^a \sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ works for any $a > 4$. I've updated the answer accordingly. One may as well replace $x^a$ with $e^{-1 / x^2}$ to avoid counting derivatives; indeed, the resulting function $f$ is $C^{\infty}$.